# Horizontal distribution/alignment

Tags: html, css, alignment

In this jsfiddle http://jsfiddle.net/byronyasgur/kUgBA/3/ I am trying to get the red on the right to match up perfectly with the yellow, however I am confused by why the inside box needs to be 338px wide, or what that figure is related to. If I make it any less the third box pops down to the next row.

There are four boxes to represent the fact that there could be any number of boxes in this design.

**HTML**

```
<div id="outer">
    <div id="container" >
        <div class="content">content</div>
        <div class="content">content</div>
        <div class="content">content</div>
        <div class="content">content</div>
    </div>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
#outer{
    width:330px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    padding: 0;
    background: yellow; 
}

#container{
    /* background: orange; */
    padding: 0;
    margin-left: -5px;
    margin-right: -5px; 

    width:338px;
}
.content {
    width: 100px;
    background: red;
    margin: 5px;
    display: inline-block;
    height: 40px;
}
```

Comment: It might help to review the CSS box model: http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/box.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's the standard behavior of inline elements. When there is no more space left, they get on a new line. Just like text inside a div, if it doesn't fit in one line, it goes on the next one...

Comment: Thanks. That was it ... I suppose I had considered the div's to be block even though I had set them to inline-block. New version of fiddle here in case it helps anyone else http://jsfiddle.net/byronyasgur/kUgBA/14/

Answer (score 0):

Is there some reason why you need that orange container div? The only way I was able to align the red with the yellow was by removing the container div and changing the width of the outer div. [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/43g2K/3/)

**HTML**

```
<div id="outer">
    <div class="content">content</div>
    <div class="content margin">content</div>
    <div class="content">content</div>
    <div class="content">content</div>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
#outer {
    width: 318px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    padding: 0;
    background: yellow; 
}

.content {
    width: 100px;
    background: red;
    display: inline-block;
    height: 40px;
}

.margin {
    margin: 5px;
}
```

Comment: Thanks but as I was saying the number of boxes is dynamic so I won't be able to put the margin class on the second, 5th, 8th etc boxes.